# How to get action on button pressed in a component to viewcontroller

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, custom-controls

I've made a UIView component, inside has 2 buttons. When a user touch the buttons, I need to call a action method of ViewController.

I've tried to pass a selector, but it crash:

on ViewController

```
component.leftAction = #selector(ViewController.myAction)

func myAction(sender: UIButton!) {
    print("tapped!")
}
```

on Component.swift

```
public var leftAction: Selector? {
    didSet {
        if (leftAction != nil){
            self.leftButton.addTarget(self, action: leftAction!, for: .touchUpInside)
        }
    }
}
```

How can I do it?

Comment: What Swift version are you using? In Swift3, the Selector syntax has changed. It needs to be `#selector(ViewController.myAction)`

Comment: @DávidPásztor Anyway it crashes: "unrecognized selector sent to instance"

Comment: Why not just `addTarget` to the button directly instead of passing it through a selector variable?

Comment: What about #selector(myAction)? Are you sure your class is called `ViewController`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's crashing because button target is wrong. In your case you are passing target as `self` which is an instance of `Component` class. Target must be your `ViewController` instance because your selector is defined in your `ViewController` class.

You can do something like this to fix your problem.

```
public var leftTargetAction: (Any, Selector)? {
    didSet {
        if let targetAction = leftTargetAction {
            self.leftButton.addTarget(targetAction.0, action: targetAction.1, for: .touchUpInside)
        }
    }
}
```

And use it like this.

```
component.leftTargetAction = (self,#selector(ViewController.myAction))
```

Answer (score 0):

Better approach would be to handle this with delegates. 
To know more about delegate you can [go through this post](https://swiftwithsadiq.wordpress.com/2017/07/20/delegate-in-swift/).

Answer (score 0):

Just change

```
component.leftAction = #selector(ViewController.myAction)
```

to

```
component.leftAction = #selector(ViewController.myAction(sender:))
```

And `ViewController` should not be deallocated.